# How to remove another duplicate y axes grid in chart.js when adding yAxes title

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Showing you an image to better understand my problem:

the first two image shows the result without yAxes scale configuration

my code without yAxes label configuration:

[image: Chart.js option without adding yAxes label configuration]

the result:

[image: Bar chart without adding yAxes label configuration]

Now I want to add yAxes title, and this is the result:

my code with yAxes label configuration:

[image: Chart.js option with yAxes label configuration]

the result:

[image: Bar chart with yAxes label configuration]

as you can see, the y axis has been dulplicated, and i just want to add the title 'Trainees'. How am i able to only display the title 'Trainees'

btw, i used chart.js v4 and react-chart-js v2

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your first Y axis is simply called `y`, which means that, by adding the `yAxis:{},` , you're creating a second axis.
What you can do is replace `yAxes:` in your code by `y:`